# implementation of AND OR graph in artificial intelligence

Tags: artificial-intelligence

How can i implement `AND-OR` graph. which data structure i can use, & which is one best? while reading algorith i read word `FUTILITY` , what is means of that?
what is `AND` arc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to your question is in question itself. you can implement AND_OR graph by using data structure GRAPH & TREE. in any language you can simply create tree or graph. & as per algorithm you can write code for it.
futility is like threshold.it is used for checking perticular condition ,it may be distance or anything.